# Echache 3.2.0 No Store.Provider found to handle configured resource types [offheap, disk] exception

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

i have recently switched from an older implementation of ehcache to  version 3.2 so i have the following xml configuration file for a project:

```
<eh:config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  xmlns:eh='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3    
  http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd">
<eh:persistence directory="C:\foo\bar\Cache-Persistence"/>
<eh:thread-pools> 
  <eh:thread-pool alias="defaultDiskPool" min-size="1" max-size="3"/>
</eh:thread-pools> 
<eh:disk-store thread-pool="defaultDiskPool"/>
<eh:cache-template name="PROC_REQTemplate">
  <eh:key-type>java.lang.String</eh:key-type>
  <eh:value-type>java.lang.String</eh:value-type>
  <eh:expiry>
    <eh:ttl>640</eh:ttl>
  </eh:expiry> 
  <eh:resources> 
    <eh:offheap unit="MB">500</eh:offheap>
    <eh:disk unit="GB" persistent="true">3</eh:disk>
  </eh:resources>
  <eh:disk-store-settings thread-pool="defaultDiskPool"/>
</eh:cache-template>
<eh:cache alias="proc_req_cache" uses-template="PROC_REQTemplate"/>
</eh:config>
```

with the above shown configuration i get the following exception trace that i keep truncated to conserve a bit of space but shows clearly the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Store.Provider found to handle configured resource types [offheap, disk] from {org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.OnHeapStore$Provider, org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.tiering.TieredStore$Provider, org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.OffHeapStore$Provider, org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore$Provider}
at org.ehcache.core.internal.store.StoreSupport.selectStoreProvider(StoreSupport.java:80) ~[?:?]
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.getStore(EhcacheManager.java:440) ~[?:?]
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createNewEhcache(EhcacheManager.java:311) ~[?:?]
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createCache(EhcacheManager.java:260) ~[?:?]
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.init(EhcacheManager.java:567) ~[?:?]
```

I thought that according to the current 3.2 documentation you can use any combination of data storage tiers but apparently this is not the case as the above error shows.So...

1. I can only make the above hown configuration to work if i comment-out the 
   offheap resource  and leave **only** the disk but not both. Is this normal? what am i missing?
2. As per the 2.7.8 version the documentation (see here [ehcache-2.8-storage-options](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/get-started/storage-options.html)) mentioned BigMemory as the offHeap store however, in ehcache-3.2.0.jar if i am seeing correctly there is some-kind of internal map for that purpose. Could the error reported above be related to the fact that i am not including BigMemory in the project? My guess is no, but it would be nice if someone could clarify?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the higher caching level (currently offheap) needs to be a caching tier (our terminology for near caching). Right now, offheap isn't. So you need an onheap level as soon as you start having layers. Here is a working configuration.

I've also set `ehcache` as default namespace to make the xml more readable. And set the `defaultThreadPool` as default to prevent you from having to set it everywhere (and alternative is to add `<event-dispatch thread-pool="defaultDiskPool"/>` because the event-dispatch needs a thread pool and there was no default).

```
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
           xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3
  http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd">

    <persistence directory="C:\foo\bar\Cache-Persistence"/>

    <thread-pools>
        <thread-pool alias="defaultDiskPool" min-size="1" max-size="3" default="true"/>
    </thread-pools>

    <cache-template name="PROC_REQTemplate">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>java.lang.String</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl>640</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">1</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">500</offheap>
            <disk unit="GB" persistent="true">3</disk>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>

    <cache alias="proc_req_cache" uses-template="PROC_REQTemplate"/>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Henri and for taking time to clean up the conf. You are ofcourse right , i managed to figure this out in the end by myself as well. What threw me off a bit was the new documentation, coupled with the fact i thought that i was getting the on heap store by default. One more question: Does one have to always configure a `<event-dispatch thread-pool="my-thread-pool"/>` ? or just when one wishes to configure Eventing? thanks again

Comment: No, the eventing always exists. So you have to give it a pool if there is no default one.

Answer (score 3):

In short, there is currently no support for having a disk tier with *just* an offheap tier. The current Ehcache 3.x support for tiering mandates a *heap* tier the moment you want to have multiple tiers.

Supported combination at this day (Ehcache 3.1.x and above):

- heap or offheap or disk or clustered (single tier)
- heap + offheap
- heap + disk
- heap + offheap + disk
- heap + clustered
- heap + offheap + clustered

The error has nothing to do with `BigMemory` which was the commercial offering on top of Ehcache 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are indeed right as well as @Henri above. I can verify that both your answers are functional and sensible. As far as BigMemory goes my intuition too was that had nothng to do with the error  but to be on the safe side i thought i would check with all the changes in the EhCache 3.x series. Unfortunately i can only give one +1 and i would have to give it to the answer above for taking the time to even edit my conf. Thanks again.